# Visual Studio 2013: "VC++ Directories" option missing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, bcg

I am currently in the process of switching from VS 2012 to VS 2013. My solution is a C++ application which refers to CodeJock (http://www.codejock.com/) and BCG (http://www.bcgsoft.com/).

And that's my problem: In VS 2012, I can add the paths to CodeJock and BCG by opening the Property Manager and adding the includes to the "Include Directories" section of the "VC++ Directories" node. In VS 2013, I don't have that node (and I also don't have it when right-clicking one of the projects of my solution). The only node I see below "Configuration Properties" is "Code Analysis".

However, if I create a new C++ project in VS 2013, the option is available.

Surprisingly, some of my co-workers have already performed the switch to VS 2013, and they didn't have that issue.

My question is: What can I do to make that option appear in VS 2013 for my solution?

Comment: maybe you can create a new project, and import the files. then modify setting.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the properties of the Project and not the Solution?

Comment: Jerry: I thought about that, but my fear is that I will then have (lots?) of outgoing changes, which I don't want to commit since everything works for my co-workers...

Comment: sgar91: Yes, I am ;-)

Comment: Nearly everything you want to know about setting build/project/solution/global properties in VS2013 can be at least started [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx). It *sounds* like you want to use a custom property sheet, but that may be swatting a fly with a sledge hammer. Scroll down to "Sharing Reusable Property Configurations" and see if its a better match for what you seek.

Comment: Do check this first on a Hello World program.  The VS installer has a knack for plowing on, even if sub-sections of the install could not be completed correctly.  Short from a mildly mannered completion message that's way too easy to ignore and a massive set of .log files in the TEMP directory that contain a diagnostic, you'll notice that files or parts of the IDE are just missing or non-functional.  Search the dd*.log files for "error".

Comment: WhozCraig: Thanks for pointing this out! The problem I see ist that the dev environments of our developers are rather different - I think that it's just not possible to come up with a .props file that would be valid for all environments (and which we could then share through source control).

Comment: Hans: What do you mean by "Do check this on a Hello World program"? I wrote that I tried with a new C++ project, and that the option was available in that case. Do you have anything else in mind?
I have found two log files which appear to be related to the VS installation, but the logfiles' dates are older than the installation date... which of the many Windows TEMP dirs were you referring to? I searched my HD for dd*.log, but only found those "too old" logfiles...
Thanks anyways for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Since I needed to get some work done, I started VS 2012 and configured it such that I could work, which I did. Later on, a co-worker suggested (without too much hope) that I should try the Windows Compatibility Assistant, which figured that VS 2013 should use compatibility settings for Windows 8 (I'm using 8.1). Curious if that would have an effect, I started VS 2013 once more, and indeed, the "VC++ Directories" option was available.

My guess is that this is not related to the compability settings, but to the fact that I first configured the projects in VS 2012, which "fixed" the project setup for VS 2013. In fact, it turned out that debugging my program became unbelievably slow in VS2013, which was apparently caused by the mentioned compatibility settings (which I had to reset).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling so hard because I could find a way to edit my include path and I kept getting directed at a menu option that didn't exist whasoever. My setup is Visual Studio Proffesional 2013 running on windows 8 and I was trying to set up a C++ dll but couldn't figure out how to include some headers. To fix it, I found VS in the file explorer, right clicked and hit "troubleshoot compatibility". It prompted me to open VS once it was done trouble shooting, and voila, the menu item was ther! (Properties/Configuration Properties had the VC++ Directors option).

Comment: "I found VS in the file explorer, right clicked and hit "troubleshoot compatibility"" - thats help for me. Thanks!